# mySQL how to update and replace

Tags: mysql

I need to insert records, but if the records exist do a replace instead. Here is what I am currently using:

```
  $sessionDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  foreach($tmpVP as $sessionVP) {
    $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sessions
                      (sessionID,sessionDate,sessionVS,sessionVP)
                      VALUES('$sessionID','$sessionDate','$sessionVS',
                      '$sessionVP')") ;
  }
```

What I really need is to update any records matching `sessionID`, `sessionVS`, and `sessionVP` and insert new records that don't match.

**EDIT:**

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
 `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `sessionID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
 `sessionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `sessionUser` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `sessionVS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `sessionVP` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `reserved` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
 KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=88 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

sessionID, sessionVP, and sessionVS are not unique. Sample:

```
sessionID                  sessionDate          sessionUser sessionVS sessionVP 
0t1m58q9ktejuhqlrjqglcoia0 2010-06-20 09:20:53  0           111111    144268736
0t1m58q9ktejuhqlrjqglcoia0 2010-06-20 09:20:53  0           111111    144268819
0t1m58q9ktejuhqlrjqglcoia0 2010-06-20 09:20:53  0           111111    144268880
```

So, if I have a new record with `0t1m58q9ktejuhqlrjqglcoia0`, `111111`, and `144268880' I need to update row #3 instead of adding row #4.

Comment: As Mark Byers suggested, check for sanitized input with e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Please post your table definition. `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you should add a unique index on `(sessionID, sessionVP, sessionVS)`. You can do this using the following command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_sessions_sessionid_sessionvs_sessionvp
ON sessions (sessionID, sessionVS, sessionVP)
```

Then there are two relatively simple ways to insert or update in MySQL. The first is to use [ON DUPLICATE UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO sessions
(sessionID,sessionDate,sessionVS,sessionVP)
VALUES
('$sessionID', '$sessionDate', '$sessionVS', '$sessionVP')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sessionDate = '$sessionDate'
```

There other is to use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

```
REPLACE INTO sessions
(sessionID,sessionDate,sessionVS,sessionVP)
VALUES
('$sessionID', '$sessionDate', '$sessionVS', '$sessionVP')
```

The second is slightly more concise, but has the disadvantage that it internally causes a delete followed by an insert.

There are also a few other issues:

- You don't need both a primary key index and an ordinary index on `ID`. Remove the ordinary index as it is redundant.
- You may have an SQL vulnerability. If you have not already validated the input you might want to consider protecting yourself by using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) as appropriate. Alternatively you could look at using query parameters.
- You are not checking for error conditions. Consider using [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) so that if your query has an error you can see what the error is. Seeing the error message can save you a lot of time debugging.

  ```
  mysql_query("...") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
  ```

Comment: You may want to include the stipulations that REPLACE has (it deletes the record and inserts a new one when "updating")

Comment: thanks for the added tips. I have them in my code, I just didn't include them in my sample.

Answer (score 4):

You might take a look at `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Another useful page that compares `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with Oracle's `MERGE`: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/05/25/mysql-merge-gone-awry/

Answer (score 1):

Add an unique key on `(sessionID, sessionVS, sessionVP)`, then use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT` (just substitute the word, syntax is the same).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table structure, I mean the primary keys you can use

```
$res = mysql_query("REPLACE INTO sessions
                      (sessionID,sessionDate,sessionVS,sessionVP)
                      VALUES('$sessionID','$sessionDate','$sessionVS',
                      '$sessionVP')") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the values part of the primary key? If yes, take a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html